# html tag not affecting appearance when sent via json

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm sending a message via json like this:

```
function getMessage() {
  $response = [
    'message' => sprintf('email sent successfully to %s', '<em>official@mysite.com</em>'),
  ];
  echo json_encode($response);
}
```

and reads the variable like this:

```html
<span id="mymessage"></span>
```

```
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'getMessage',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(res) {
      $('#mymessage').text(res.message);
    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.log(err.responseText);
    }
  });
});
```

I expected the result like this: email sent successfully to *official@mysite.com*
but instead I get the result like this: `email sent successfully to <em>official@mysite.com</em>`

why is the `<em>` tag still showing as plain string instead of making the text to become italic?

Comment: why are you using `sprintf()` why dont you use direct string?

Comment: because the string is stored in a variable. I'm using codeigniter so it's in the language helper. is it because of the `sprintf()`?

Comment: did you try direct string ?

Comment: yes. I've just tried changing the code into plain string but the `<em>` tag is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below changes, first direct string to response and `html()` in js
php:

```
function getMessage() {
  $response = [
    'message' => 'email sent successfully to '.'<em>official@mysite.com</em>'
  ];
  echo json_encode($response);
  exit();
}
```

js:

```
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'getMessage',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(res) {
      $('#mymessage').html(res.message);
    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.log(err.responseText);
    }
  });
});
```

if it will work with `.html()` then you can use your `sprintf()` too in php

Comment: thank you. the `.html()` in the js part does the trick even with `sprintf()` in the PHP. I thought `<span>` always has to use `.text()`? anyway.. as long as it works, eh?